# GWmodel ggwr.basic not found

Tags: r, gwmodel

I have been trying to use the function ggwr.basic from the GWmodel package in R for a few days. I need to adjust a gwr binomial model for some data so I am using ggwr.basic(). The package is apparently well installed and loaded before calling the function, but when I invoke ggwr.basic() I get the following error message:

```
Error: could not find function "ggwr.basic"
```

I am able to use other functions from the package or even call help(ggwr.basic) and access the help section of the funcion.

Just to be as clear as possible I am using R 64-bit version 3.3.1 and GWmodel 2.0.1.

Here is the example code I am using:

```
##install.packages('GWmodel')
library(GWmodel)

data(LondonHP)
DM<-gw.dist(dp.locat=coordinates(londonhp))
bw.f2 <- bw.ggwr(BATH2~FLOORSZ,data=londonhp, dMat=DM,family ="binomial")
res.binomial<-ggwr.basic(BATH2~FLOORSZ, bw=bw.f2,data=londonhp, dMat=DM, family ="binomial")
```

Does anyone know if this is a common error am I doing something wrong??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a problem with the package. `ggwr.basic` is mentioned in the docs however it is not exported. You should contact Binbin Lu binbinlu@whu.edu.cn on this.

However, this works:

```
res.binomial<-GWmodel::gwr.basic(BATH2~FLOORSZ, bw=bw.f2,data=londonhp, dMat=DM)
```

You can also use the `gwr.binomial()` function.

This may have just been a typo in the docs, wherein he meant to refer to the functions above. However, you should check with him. Even if it was just a typo, he should fix it.